# I want to re-write /app_mine.php to /mine

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

What i think i am looking for is a RegEx that will look ahead and look behind, and match just the mine part.

I have tried various RegExes with no success. I am using Apache 2.2.22

Enabled mod_rewrite.
Appended

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^app_([^.]+)\.php$ to /$1 [L,NC]
```

to .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT

When trying to access my app DOCUMENT_ROOT/envName/route i get 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Could you include those various regexes in your question?

Comment: Please provide sample input, sample output and you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `/app_mine.php to /mine` or else from `/app_anything.php to /anything` you can use following code.

**PS:** I haven't used `look ahead and look behind` as stated in your question (though it can be used). But unless you provide some concrete examples I think we can avoid using look arounds here.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+app_([^.]+)\.php([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)([^.]*)$ app_$1.php$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Ah sorry! there was a typo earlier. I just fixed it, please try now.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/app_dev.php/admin/home works. http://127.0.0.1/dev/admin/home gives a very prompt Not found error

Comment: You never gave sample of input URLs and my answer was just based on your question title. What do you want this URI `/app_dev.php/admin/home` to become?

Comment: /dev/admin/home. Thank you so much!

Comment: Now it works. Thank you very much! But Symfony2 tries to find the route, and throws No route found for "GET /dev/admin/users". I am clueless. I will probably post another thread, thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome, when you post new question pls don't forget to link this one for reference so that you will get better answers.